# How to fix delete modal from bootstrap ( delete only the first row )

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I have a problem when I want to delete a row, it delete only the first one , I'm using php and bootstrap modal

**ajout.php** this page is where I call deleteEntreprise.php with an id

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','root');

$pdoStat = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM entreprise');

$ExecuteIsOk = $pdoStat->execute();

$entreprises = $pdoStat->fetchAll()


<?php foreach ($entreprises as $entreprise): ?>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >
        <?= $entreprise['id'] ?>
      </td>
    <td>
      <a href="liste.php?id=<?= $entreprise['id'] ?>" style="text-decoration : none !important; color : white  !important;"><?= $entreprise['nom'] ?></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Supprimer
      </button>
    </td>
  </tbody>

</tr>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ATTENTION !</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Etes-vous sûr(e) de vouloir supprimer le compte ?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
      <a href="deleteEntreprise.php?id=<?= $entreprise['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Supprimer le compte</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**deleteEntreprise.php** sql query for delete an entreprise

```
<?php

// Cette fonction permet de supprimer une fiche entreprise de la base données

$entreprise_id = $_GET['id'];

require 'inc/db.php';
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM entreprise WHERE id = ?');
$req->execute([$entreprise_id]);
$user = $req->fetch();
session_start();


    $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM entreprise WHERE id = ? ')->execute([$entreprise_id]);

    $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'Lentreprise a bien été supprimer de la base de données.';
    // $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
    header('Location: ajout.php');
exit();
```

I hope I have given enough info to help solve my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks and have a nice day !

Comment: did u print $entreprise array inside foreach?

Comment: like <?= $entreprise['id'] ?> ?

Comment: <?= $entreprise['id'] ?>  is this always same ?

Comment: Noo i'ts not always the same:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<table>
  <tbody>

  <?php foreach ($entreprises as $entreprise): ?>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <?= $entreprise['id'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="liste.php?id=<?= $entreprise['id'] ?>" style="text-decoration: none!important; color: white!important;"><?= $entreprise['nom'] ?></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#exampleModal<?= $entreprise['id'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal">Supprimer</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?= $entreprise['id'];?>" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ATTENTION !</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Etes-vous sûr(e) de vouloir supprimer le compte ?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
            <a href="deleteEntreprise.php?id=<?= $entreprise['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Supprimer le compte</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The modal you were using had a static `id`, so I made it dynamic by adding `$entreprise['id]` to it for every row, and updated the link in the delete button. Now every row has its own unique modal. You also had some misplaced HTML tags in your code, which couldn't have helped. Please feel free to upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues in your code is, you are referring to all the the modal HTML created under the same ID. So if you have multiple items within your PHP loop, how are you going to determine which ID should be deleted.

In your code `<?php foreach ($entreprises as $entreprise): ?>` how is the array `$enterprises` constructed? You don't show any code of the element ID being removed. I'm guessing that you are reading in from a database of sorts, if so, again, how is the element in question removed from the database such that when the PHP runs, it does not return the deleted element.

In there instances, sometimes showing all of the code required for the functionality you are after, helps people to help you.